# Генерация страницы из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Решаю такую задачу в написании своего фреймворка и cms: из базы данных подгружаются небольшие фрагменты html кода, а также php-скрипты.

В базе запись выглядит так, например:

```
<div style="font-size: 18px;"><? echo "тест";?></div>
```

При выводе, пишу так подключение к базе и вывод данных:

```
$where = 'id = 1';    
$Current_page  = $BDConnect->select('pages', Array('*'), $where);    
foreach ($Current_page as $html) echo $html['text_page'];
```

В результате на странице пишет тектом текст:

```
<div><? echo "тест";</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы это был не текст, а часть html-кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно `echo` заменить на `eval()`. И, так как у Вас это HTML код, то обрамить его тегами

```
foreach ($Current_page as $html)
  eval('?> ' . $html['text_page']);
```

но помните, что функция `eval()` очень опасна из-за возможности исполнить любой код

Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php)

> **Предостережение**
>   Использование eval() может быть очень опасно, поскольку позволяет исполнить произвольный код. Использование данной функции не рекомендуется. Если вы полностью убеждены, что нет иного способа воспроизведения необходимого функционала, обратите особое внимание на исключения обработки таким образом данных, вводимых пользователем, без специальной обработки и валидации.

Comment: В каком смысле опасна? Подмена кода что ли возможна при генерации кода?

Comment: @IntegralAL Вы уверены, что в базе у Вас не окажется какого-нибудь вредоносного кода?

Comment: за eval в любом коде, и не только php нужно по рукам давать

Comment: @tcpack4 Это неконструктивно. Если у вас есть лучший ответ - добавьте его.

Comment: @tcpack4 Полностью согласен. Но других вариантов решения задачи я не вижу

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov. Код создает администратор, поэтому вредоносного кода не будет там. Про eval тоже сомнения есть. Может тогда подскажете, как правильно смоделировать структуру системы? Есть данные в базе в виде фрагментов кода, либо своего кода [[Блог]], [[магазин id='5']] и в индексном файле пользовательского фрондэнда нужно вывести генерацию кода в виде цельной страницы, возможно, через контроллер распарсивания таких тегов.

Comment: @IntegralAL идея со спецтегами гораздо лучше

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov.,обрамлять теги в любом случае придется в html код, потому что без такого сформировать корректную страницу.

Comment: Возможно вам стоит отказаться от хранения кода в базе и хранить код в файлах. Если посмотреть на примеры современных CMS, там есть понятие плагина - это некий блок, который кладем в отдельную папочку и который вызывается определенным образом.

Comment: Полностью задача в вопросе не поставлена, но ей богу - хранить PHP-код в базе и потом выполнять его через eval чревато труднонаходимыми ошибками, когда код будет делать не то, что ожидал автор.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял по поводу структуры. Реально нужно пересмотреть концепцию пользовательского контента в пользу файлового формирования сайта. Всем спасибо за поддержку и ответы! Помогли.